# Firebird datetime format

Tags: sql, datetime, firebird

I have VTS function that transform the data into datetime.
My aim is to select datetime with this specific format `(MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm)`.

The initial data in **TIME** column (Int64):

```
131473080013710000
131473080026060000
131473080039030000
```

Transform with **VTS(string)** function `(select VTS("TIME"))`

```
20170816000001.3710000
20170816000002.6060000
20170816000003.9030000
```

Needed result (YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm):

```
2017-08-16 00:00
2017-08-16 00:00
2017-08-16 00:00
```

I tried with: `select VTS("TIME", 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')`.
ErrorMessage: `function VTS could not be matched`

Comment: What is "VTS function"? Anyway, formatting values is best done by client, not in SQL statement.

Comment: `select VTS("TIME", 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')` - this is NOT real query, it does not contain "from <table name>" clause. Or you do not use Firebird SQL server but some different non-Firebird database

Comment: `specific format (MM-DD-YYYY ` and `Needed result (YYYY-MM-DD`  - so what format do you need? And do you need formatted string output or date output ?

Comment: VTS its external function:

DECLARE EXTERNAL FUNCTION VTS
 BIGINT
 RETURNS CSTRING(128) CHARACTER SET NONE FREE_IT

I know that the query is not full, I have put only the part that I need, of course there is from table after that.

The format needed as already wrote is 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'.

Comment: `CHARACTER SET NONE` asking for trouble in future maintenance....  You wrote TWO different date formats and I quoted them both

Comment: http://www.firebirdtest.com/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-overlay

Comment: answering questions - like VTS declaration - are to be added into the question itself. Edit the question  and add the VTS function, also tell remove one of two ambiguous formats, leave only one that you really need

Comment: What is this VTS function, where did you get it? It is not a standard Firebird function, so you need to include all relevant information. If it is your own function, then modify it so it does what you want, if it is a function written by someone else, then you need ask them. In any case your question is unclear as to exactly what help you need, and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Since the VTS function reportedly returns textual data (but `CHARACTER SET NONE` is really fragile and would likely cause problems in future! ) you now can manipulate that text with string functions without looking into what that text mean.

See string functions at http://www.firebirdtest.com/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs.html

It is not quite clear which of many formats you quoted you really want.

> select datetime with this specific format (**MM-DD-YYYY** HH:mm).
>   Needed result (**YYYY-MM-DD** HH:mm):

We would stick with the latter as you quoted it twice in the question.

Next question whether you want to get text or date form the server.
Supposedly you want to have a formatted text as SQL server output, not the native date value.

Then you need to do three steps with the values like `'20170816000001.3710000'`.

1. Remove all the digits past the YYYYMMDD part.
2. Separate DD, MM and YYYY parts with dashes
3. Append " 00:00" to the string.

Step 1:

```
 select Left('20170816000001.3710000', 8) from rdb$Database

 "20170816"
```

Step 2:

```
select Overlay(
  Overlay(
     Left('20170816000001.3710000', 8)
     PLACING '-' FROM 7 FOR 0)
  PLACING '-' FROM 5 FOR 0)
from rdb$Database

"2017-08-16"
```

Step 3:

```
select Overlay( Overlay( Left('20170816000001.3710000', 8)
  PLACING '-' FROM 7 FOR 0) PLACING '-' FROM 5 FOR 0) || ' 00:00'
from rdb$Database

"2017-08-16 00:00"
```

However usually it is wrong idea to convert Date to text at SQL server level.
Normally you return plain Date value form the server, and it is your **application** that should format that date into any text format of your choice.

```
select cast(
  Overlay( Overlay(
     Left('20170816000001.3710000', 8)
     PLACING '-' FROM 7 FOR 0) PLACING '-' FROM 5 FOR 0) 
  as date )
from rdb$Database
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.
The datetime format order is not so important, If i have YYYMMDD solution, i can easily convert to DDMMYYYY.


Other thing is that you are working above with the numbers that I gave you, but these are just example, I'm not planning to do the same with thousands retrieved records.

I need somehow to use the "select VTS("TIME") and to convert the result to looks like date time YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.

Comment: You replace the constant with VTS function call. That is ABC of programming and everyone knows it, so I do not highlight it. I instead show you step by step how you transform the string from the place you stopped to the place you want to reach. Also I suggest you to use the last option, to get the non-formatted non-string native date value from server, and then use your APPLICATION that will format the date value into any text representation you may like.